# Python code to load CSV data from Google Storage to Bigquery?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am pretty new in this, so wanted to have code and process to load data from csv file (Placed in Google Storage) to BigQuery Table using the python code and DataFlow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question so we can help.

Comment: In fact you have to explain your problem and what have you tried so far and why it doesn't worked so far, not just come and ask about tutorials.

Despite, as it is, this is a low quality question because it's to broad, you can check here the documentation about ["Loading CSV data into a new table"](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_new_table)

Answer (score 3):

There are different BigQuery libraries depending on the language. For Python you would find [this one](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries).

But if what you want is the exactly piece of code to upload CSV from Google Cloud Storage to Bigquery, this example might work for you: ["Loading CSV data into a new table"](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#bigquery-load-table-gcs-csv-create-python)

You can see also in the same documentation page ["Appending to or overwriting a table with CSV data"](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#appending_to_or_overwriting_a_table_with_csv_data).

You can go also to the GitHub in order to check [all the methods available for Python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/851ed7028d0d34f88f0cdf2c0fefeb0873dba484/docs/bigquery/snippets.py).